# Linking two access databases in C#

Tags: c#, ms-access, ado.net, ado

I have a c# winforms app that will be connecting to 2 access databases. One is a reporting database which I wont be amending, and the other database is where the app will make updates etc.  There will be a need for queries which join tables in the two databases.  I am planning to use OleDBConnection, OleDBDataReader etc to issue queries.  However, I cannot work out how to link the databases programmatically as you would be able to do via Access itself.
In the VB6\ActiveX world, I would have used use the ADODX Catalog object etc to create a link between the two access databases, allowing me to query one as if all the tables from the other are within it.

However, I dont think using the ADODX component in a .net app is such a good idea, as Microsoft say "ADO and ADO MD have not been fully tested in a Microsoft .NET Framework environment. They may cause intermittent issues, especially in service-based applications or in multithreaded applications. The techniques that are discussed in this article should only be used as a temporary measure during migration to ADO.NET. " see http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317881

So, what I am looking for is a way of doing a similar thing but without using old COM/ActiveX stuff.  My goal is to be able to write one query which can join tables on both databases.

Can anyone think if a way to do this?  Could I create a DataSet object containing all the tables and do it like that somehow?

I am familiar with querying Access databases, DML etc but I want to know how to link the two databases.

Thanks in advance
Jonathan

Comment: If you are dealing with low number of data, you can load the data into Lists/collections .net and join using LINQ or expression. Or is there any specific reason to use JOIN?

Comment: Hi I see your point.  In general data volumes will not be high although some tables may have thousands of rows.  I think some queries can be done like this although we are historically a SQL shop so the other devs will moan they dont understand ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `System.Data.Odbc` then you can open an `OdbcConnection` to one database and refer to a table in another database within a query using `[;Database=...].[TableName]` like this:

```cs
using (var cmd = new OdbcCommand())
{
    // con is an open OdbcConnection to C:\Users\Public\Database1.accdb
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.CommandText =
            @"SELECT c.LastName, m.MonthName " +
                @"FROM " +
                    @"[Clients] c " +
                    @"INNER JOIN " +
                    @"[;Database=C:\Users\Public\mdbTest.mdb].[Months] m " +
                        @"ON c.RenewalMonth = m.MonthID " +
                @"WHERE c.ID = 2";
```

Comment: Thats excellent I wasn't aware you could do queries like that in Access.  Actually if I had framed my question as "how do you join tables in different databases in Access" I thik I would have found this on Google ;-)